# I want to show amount by category credit or debit I only receive credit amount

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have one amount column in my table and I want to show that amount by category credit or debit  I only receive credit amount.

Controller

```
 <?php foreach($modResult as $voucher):?>
            <tr>
              <th>Voucher No.</th>
              <th>Voucher Amount BY CR.</th>
              <th>Voucher Amount BY DR.</th>
             <tr>

        <tr> 
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_no'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_amount'] = $voucher['voucher_transaction_type']=='CR' ? $voucher['voucher_amount'] : '';?></td>

 <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_amount'] = $voucher['voucher_transaction_type']=='DR' ? $voucher['voucher_amount'] : '';?></td>
          </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model

```
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('ts_voucher');

            $this->db->where('voucher_category','cash_receipt');
            $this->db->or_where('voucher_category','cash_payment');

           $query=$this->db->get();
           return $query->result_array();
```

How I can show DR value in Voucher Amount BY DR column

Comment: category is in another table?

Comment: No category is in same table @DanishAli

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_transaction_type'] == 'CR' ? $voucher['voucher_amount'] : '';?></td>

 <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_transaction_type'] == 'DR' ? $voucher['voucher_amount'] : '';?></td>
```

Read more [conditional operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_conditional_operator_examples.htm)